# Extract relevant sentences based on input words NLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to build a app that finds relevant sentences in a document based on keywords or statements that a user enters. Performing this manually using a needle in the haystack approach seems highly inefficient.

Is there a ideal approach or library that can tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The field that deals with problems like you described is called [information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

A simplest method of doing such queries is based on [bag of words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) - you treat documents as vectors, such that their cosine similarity corresponds to containing similar words.

In Python you can do it for example using utilities from `scikit-learn` (this would be low level) or do stuff using more production-ready tools like [whoosh](http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) - see [Python for Humanities](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fbkarsdorp/python-course/blob/master/Chapter%208%20-%20PDF%20Search%20App.ipynb) for a sample tutorial.

If you want to dig deeper, I encourage you to read [Information Retrieval book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html), at least couple of first chapters.